# What is "Ribbon Graph"?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I am studying graphs on surfaces. But I am confused about the definition of "Ribbon Graph".

Let $(\Gamma, I)$ be  a graph. For $v\in V$ the star of $v$ $$E_v=\{e\in E \mid v= e_-\}$$ is the set of edges starting from $v$. A ribbon graph is the graph $(\Gamma, I)$, together a cyclic ordering on the star of every vertex.

The definitions are given [here](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf).

I am confused how to define cyclic ordering on the star of every vertex. I have tried the following diagram. Here, $v$ be a vertex, and we have $8$ vertex starting from $v$. Now I am confused how to define cyclic ordering on $v$?
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyclic ordering in a ribbon graph is meant to be a discrete representation of a geometric difference between two embeddings of a graph in the same surface.

For example, consider the two planar embeddings below:

[image: Two embeddings of a graph with edges 01, 02, 03, 04, 12 as described in the text]

The vertices and the adjacencies between them are the same in both pictures, so as abstract graphs they are the same. However, as embeddings they are different: in the first picture, vertices $3$ and $4$ are on the same side of the cycle $(0,1,2,0)$, and in the second picture, they are on different sides.

A ribbon graph also captures that difference, but in a different way. In this graph, the star of $0$ is the set of four edges $\{01, 02, 03, 04\}$. The *cyclic ordering* around vertex $0$ is $(01,02,03,04)$ in the first diagram and $(01,03,02,04)$ in the second. This is a *cyclic* ordering because the starting point of $1$ was arbitrary: $(01,02,03,04)$ and $(02,03,04,01)$ are the same cyclic ordering, both of them describing what happens in the left diagram. However, no cyclic shift will turn this into $(01,03,02,04)$, so the two cyclic orderings we get from different diagrams are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, is ribbon graph  a graph with a cyclic ordering (here, clockwise) defined each of vertices? Should all the cyclic ordering of all the vertices have the same direction (i.e, if one is clockwise then all the others would be clockwise)? Am I right?

Comment: Also how to define the cyclic ordering for the vertex $3$ and $4$ in the second figure? I am asking this because we vertex $3$ and $4$ have only one edge incident to them, i.e.  star of vertex $3$ is $30$ and star of vertex $4$ is $04$. Please tell.

Comment: If you're going from a plane embedding to a ribbon graph, then yes, the cyclic orderings should all have the same direction. (Once we have the ribbon graph, we often forget about the embedding it came from, or whether it came from an embedding at all, at which point there's no "clockwise" or "counterclockwise" - just the cyclic ordering.)

Comment: When there is only one edge incident on a vertex, there's only one possible cyclic ordering: something like "$(30)$" for vertex $3$. Actually, even if there are only two edges, the cyclic ordering is unique: for vertex $1$, for example, we have edge $\{10,12\}$ but $(10,12)$ and $(12,10)$ are the same *cyclic* ordering.